# editing the same cell in the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, gridview

hello i am creating a shopping application , I have a shopping cart in that i have some columns which are add from the code behind and some columns are of template fields which are not present in the database but want use in future.

this is my shopping cart

code :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewProduct" runat="server" CellPadding="5" CssClass="grid"
    ForeColor="#333333" OnRowCreated="GridViewProduct_RowCreated" OnRowDataBound="GridViewProduct_RowDataBound"
    ShowFooter="True" CellSpacing="1" 
    onrowupdating="GridViewProduct_RowUpdating">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:ButtonField Text="Remove From Cart" CommandName="RemoveFromCart" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxQuantity" runat="server" Width="50px">1</asp:TextBox><br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonEditQuantity" runat="server"  CommandName="EditTextBox">edit</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonUpdate" runat="server">Update</asp:LinkButton>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Price">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="LabelTotalPrice" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F8FAFA" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#246B61" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D4DFE1" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#15524A" />
</asp:GridView>
```

[image]

i have a edit link button in the template field and the update link button in the editItem template and textbox above it so as to edit the textbox when a person clicks the edit link button.

My Question is that : How can i edit the textbox in the same column instead of whole row.

and which method should i use of the to achieve to editing the same cell rowupdating,rowcommand and save the values in session and multiply the edited value as quantity and unit price to show in the total price rows of the gridview .

please help me to implement right way to implement this as i am stuck with this for many days.. please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your gridview templates, look at the EditRowTemplate, you will see that it contains all the editable controls (most likely textboxes) delete the textboxes and add Labels instead and bind them to your datasource. That way the data is still displayed but wont be editable (except for the control that you want to be edited)

Try it and let me know if you need more help.

Comment: I Have added label and set its text property to default 1. now i have to edit the label when the user wishes to edit Quantity in the shopping cart. how could i achieve this and Which method of gridview should i use to multiple it to the unitprice and show the total value in the totalprice in other column. i edit my post to show my shopping cart pic.

Comment: OK, how are you binding the data to the gridview on codebehind? I should have copied and pasted your code from the beginning, I just did and seems like your textbox is already editable so you dont need to do anything on the EditItemTemplate(meaning that you can change the value, but if you mean something else please explain) To calculate the total based on the value of the Quantity do it on RowDataBound event like this http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2008/10/31/summing-columns-in-a-gridview.aspx

Comment: i have three databound Fields (ProductName, ProductUnitPrice, ProductAuthor) and two Template fields which are not bound to any datasource. I have just created them to enable the user to update quantity and show the total price there is no element quantity in my products database. So do i need to make a gridview column databound to make it editable or i can edit a label to. please reply..

Comment: Common practice is to bound the columns on the gridview (GV) to column in the DataTable, that would make your life much easier, specially if you are going to save that quantity into your database, its going to save you a lot of time. Once you link the column in GV to your dataset you will be able to utilize its databound templates (Edit, Item) and you wont have to worry about writing procedures that will take the element's value and then creating a SQL statement to Update the value, the Gridview will do it for you.

Comment: I see your picture is different from your original code because in your OC your column has a textbox ready to accept the potential change in values. I suggest leave the textbox in from the beginning and then use Javascript to do your calculation and update the label with the total. How do you plan to submit the quantity/total?